# Counting model field dynamically?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Is it possible to count a model field dynamically in django.  I have tried using override save model but this is not dynamic:

```
class MyAdminView(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       super(MyAdminView, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Models.py

```
class JobRequest(models.Model):
    User=models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete = model.CASCADE)
    organization=models.CharField(max_length =150)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length =150)
    country= models.CharField(max_length =150)
    state=models.CharField(max_length =150)
    offer=models.BooleanField(default =True)
    active = models.IntegerField(max_length =150)
    present=models.IntegerField(max_length =150)
```

I am building a site where users apply for job placement . I will want the **present** field to count the number of times a user submit a job request and the **active** field to count the number of offers a user has gotten.

Comment: In general, if something can be calculated from the data present in the database, you should not save it. But it's not clear what should be counted (and why a count, which is an integer, should be saved in a CharField). Can you give an example with some data so we understand what you're trying to save in `present`?

Comment: @dirkgroten what if you need to filter by it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the question.

Comment: @SamCreamer you can usually filter on calculated values using annotations

Comment: @flow but there are multiple `JobRequest` rows for the same user. You want to update the `active` and `present` fields on all of them when one gets changed/added? See why it doesn't make sense to store that in a field?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dirkgroten. A user can only apply for a specific job once. I am asking to enable me know which user has more jobs (in terms of numbers) assigned and those with less or no jobs.

Comment: What you say makes no sense with the model you're showing. The `JobRequest` doesn't have any link to "a specific job". `JobRequest.objects.filter(user=user).count()` tells you how many job requests a user has. That's the only thing that can be counted with the model you're showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want shouldn't be a field on the `JobRequest` model, since it can easily be retrieved from the db. Ideally this should be a property on your `User` model since it belongs to a user. But you can also make it a property on the `JobRequest` instances:

```
@property
def present(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()

@property
def active(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.filter(user=self.user, offer=True).count()
```

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten.